# Can I run iOS UI Tests in parallel on Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, testing, firebase-test-lab

I see Firebase now supports iOS testing in the Test Lab.  Is it going to be possible to run iOS UI  tests in parallel using Firebase?  For instance, if I have 100 iOS UI tests can I run 10 of them on 10 different devices at the same time instead of all 100 on the same device which would take much more time?

Thanks,

-Matt

Comment: If you want to have a discussion with people about Test Lab, try joining the Firebase slack in the #test-lab channel.  http://firebase.community/

Answer (score 1):

While automatic sharding of tests is not a current feature in Firebase Test Lab for iOS, it should be possible to script a solution to do what you want. You will need to create a separate .xctestrun file to run each subgroup of tests, and then use the gcloud CLI to submit each subgroup to its own device (you could send them all to the same device type, or a mix of devices, as you see fit).